# Button Tapped Frequently

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uibutton, recorder

I'm trying to make a button play a sound which is about 1 second.I Changed the event to "Touch Down" so when the button is pressed, it starts playing the sound. The problem is that if I press the button during that 1 second playing, nothing happens and i have to wait until the sound is over. but I want the button to ignore the current audio and start playing it again.(Kinda like a video game with a bang shot when the user presses the shoot button twice). How can i achieve this in swift?

here's the code for the button :

```
@IBAction func secondButton(sender: UIButton) {

    brain.soundPlayer.play()

} // brain.soundplayer records anaudio and the button it as the sound.
```

Comment: by showing us your code so we can think up how to alter it to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: it's a fairly simple button. i'll post it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `currentTime` of your `AVAudioPlayer` to 0. Then use `play`.

```
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! guess i'm a real noob in this game :|

Comment: No problem! Always happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop and restart the sound when the button is pushed.

```
@IBAction func secondButton(sender: UIButton) {
    brain.soundPlayer.stop()
    brain.soundPlayer.play() 
}
```